# Running JavaFX jar on Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, javafx, jar

I'm unable to run jar files of JavaFX applications on my Ubuntu virtual machine and I don't know why. It just says that it can't find the main file of the jar. Other jars of for example Swing applications seem to work fine. This is what I get when I run `java -version` on Ubuntu:

[image]

It seems like it has Java 8 where JavaFX should be included by default, so why can't I run the jars?

Edit: The jar consists of one class that looks like this:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
        public static void main(String[] args) {launch(args);}
        public void start(Stage ps) {
                ps.show();
        }
}
```

And it was created with the command `jar cfe javafxjar.jar Main Main.class`

The jar executes without problems on Windows 10, but fails with this message on Ubuntu:
[image]

Comment: It might be that those jars do not contain a main class or it is not properly referenced. Do the same jar files run in different environments? For further advise you should post some more details on the jar file your are trying to execute.

Comment: Made an edit with additional information, hope it can help someone diagnose the problem.

Comment: Hey @Justsomeguy, I'm having the same problem with my Ubuntu. Even the simplest "Hello World" program (that DOES run on Windows) won't run due to a "could not find or load main class" error. Did you manage to fix the problem?

Comment: @OmriSoudry. I didn't solve this if I remember correctly, but it wasn't all that important to me anyway. I wish you luck.

Answer (score 1):

Today I've also bumped into this problem.

In my case the reason was OpenJDK. 
It does not contain OpenJFX by default.

The solution was: `sudo apt-get install openjfx`

And now all works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be due to the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS:

```
$ unset JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
$ java -jar javafxjar.jar
```